# How to check if User Logged in or Not using Session Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, struts-1

I am working on struts2. I use below code to check if the User have logged in or not

```
public String execute()
{
   HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
   HttpSession        session = request.getSession(false);

   System.out.println(session);

   if(session == null)
   {
      return "UserLoggedIn";    
   }

   return "success";
}
```

When I access print the session value in console first time it print null. But when I do the same thing by refreshing the page it prints some thing like below and its ends up letting the user to access the page with out logging in.

```
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@16f21478
```

How to carry out session checking to see whether user logged in or not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html

Comment: The presence of a session says nothing about whether or not a user has logged in, rather whether or not there's a session. Sessions are created by either the JSP page itself or an interceptor. Check for the presence of a valid session value instead. Also, it's unlikely you really want to do this in an action, but rather an interceptor or filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you are just doing this for learning purpose, i believe its better to store a variable in `session`, once user logged in.

Say, when use click login button and if credentials provided by user are correct you can store a variable (logged-in) in to session and on clicking log-out button can clear this variable.

However there are few more things you need to take care.

Its better to use `SessionAware` interface provided by Struts2 which is a clean way to inject Session as Map in you action class.

```
public class YouAction implements SessionAware{
    private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
      @Override
        public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sessionMap) {
            this.sessionMap = sessionMap;
        }
    }
```

Above way let you action independent from direct dependencies from HTTP objects, which can be helpful in unit testing.

If you have the option can use Spring security which is a much better way to handle User authentication and Authorization process.

Answer (score 1):

When user logged in  put a variable in session.When logout clear that one from session.

Then check that variable in session .

Comment: You mean like this. if(session.getAttribute("UserName") == null)